# Bash: moving a group of files of a certain size with grep, awk and xargs

Tags: macos, bash, awk, xargs, mv

At work, I need to upload images to a website. They cannot be larger than 300 KB. In order to group the images that are ready to be uploaded, I devised the following line in Bash:

```
du -h * | grep "[0-2]..K" | awk '{print $2}' | xargs mv Ready/
```

This did not work, however, because the shell returned the following:

```
usage: mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source target
       mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source ... directory
```

Finally, I resorted to a for-loop to accomplish the same:

```
for file in $(du -h * | grep "[0-2]..K" | awk '{print $2}')
do
    mv -v ${file} Ready/
done
```

Can somebody explain why the first line doesn't work? It is probably something very simple I'm missing, but I can't seem to find it.

I'm on Mac OS X 10.7, Bash version 4.3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use the `find` command to get all files smaller than a certain size, makes the code a lot cleaner and easier to read like so:

```
find . -size -300k -name *.png -exec mv {} Ready/ \;
```

The reason your first command fails is because you have to reference the value you are piping in since it is not at the end of the statement. This should work:

```
du -h * | grep "[0-2]..K" | awk '{print $2}' | xargs -0 -I {} mv {} Ready/
```

Comment: Your answer is exactly to the point. The problem is that the files must go before "Ready/". Both solutions you propose have the disadvantage of spawning one mv command per affected file, while xargs in the original question tries to invoke as few xargs as possible. I could not find a way to circumvent that easily, though. xargs in -I mode and find -exec can not collect file names and put the into multiple arguments at the place you put {}.

Comment: Thanks! Could you expand a little bit on "reference the value you are piping in since it is not at the end of the statement"? Does this mean that the standard out of the `awk` statement doesn't get piped to the standard in of the `xargs` statement?

Comment: @Neftas What I meant by that was that if you use xargs as you have done in your first example, it places whatever you are piping in at the _end_ thus your command is trying to move the folder 'Ready' into whatever files are being piped in from awk. Which is why you are getting the shell error I would imagine.

Comment: @MichaelKarcher Ah yes, that is correct. You will get a spawn for each file that you see which could potentially be a performance bottleneck. Not sure how to resolve that one either off the top of my head...

Comment: @Caleb, on Linux, I would try to solve that by changing the last bit to `xargs mv -t Ready/`. But the Mac OS X terminal emulator doesn't seem to support that.

Comment: @Neftas, here's a handy reference for Mac man pages: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/#